# Dynamic CSV Header in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a csv file via Python3.

While parsing another file into this CSV, I don't know the exact number of columns I will get, so can anyone help me out how can I write a dynamic header in my CSV file based on the number of inputs I receive after parsing.

Below it is the example:

```
name,numberOfStudents,grade1,grade2,grade3, ... ,gradeN
```

The number of grades it is unknown, this is why I just need a sequence which will serve as a header.

I know I can write something like `writerow(['name', 'numberOfStudents', 'grade1', 'grade2' ... ]` but this cannot be the case if I do receive more than 200 grades (potentially)

P.S I am using `csv module` in Python and especially `writerow(row)` method of this module.

Comment: Please post the code you have so far. It will make it a lot easier to help you with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the .csv to a dictionary and then get the keys.

```
def read_csv_to_dict(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        a = [{k: v for k, v in row.items()} for row in csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=';')]
    return a

data = read_csv_to_dict('sample.csv')
print(data[0].keys())
```

Modify the data as you want.

And then use a similar approach to write the data (a list of dictionaries, one line per row in the csv)

```
def write_dict_to_csv(file_path, my_dict):
    keys = my_dict[0].keys()
    with open(file_path, 'w') as output_file:
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=';', lineterminator='\n')
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a function like this to generate your header depending on the number of grades you get:

```
def func(number_of_grades):
    header = ['name','numberOfStudents']
    for grade_number in range(1, number_of_grades):
        header.append('grade' + str(grade_number))
    print(header)
    return header
```